# Birt Report skipping letters/lines after 4000 characters stored in LONGDESCRIPTION CLOB field

Tags: oracle, birt, clob, maximo

When I am running a report which have more than 40000 character in longdescription  clob field in oracle  the report is skipping some lines/letters ,what can be done in this case so it should not skip any letters.

Comment: Are you able to provide a minimal, reproducible [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the BIRT report causing the problem?  Also it's not clear whether you have 4,000 or 40,000 characters in the LD field.